# Force close after using camera

Tags: java, javascript, android

kindly help me to solve this problem I am unable to resume my activity once I get to the camera activity.
- I have a button in my Camera activity to go to the next activity which is my `OpenurlActivity`. but when I click on back button I got this error on my logcat:

```
 08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
 resume activity {com.example.qrreader/com.example.qrreader.CameraTestActivity}:     
  java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):   at  
 android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
 08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):   at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2854)
  08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):  at    
  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
 08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):   at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):   at 
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at  
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
 08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):   at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
com.example.qrreader.CameraTestActivity.onResume(CameraTestActivity.java:510)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1202)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5328)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815)
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    ... 10 more
```

Why has this error occurred?

Comment: Post your onResume() method of previous activity.

Comment: At line 510, something is null! Posting your code would help!

Answer (score 1):

```
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 17:49:55.518: E/AndroidRuntime(13628):    at 
com.example.qrreader.CameraTestActivity.onResume(CameraTestActivity.java:510)
```

You have to check a variable at row 510 to not be null.

> i saw that the method called by onResume, the camera was null

Than you have what is the problem, obviously need to initialise the camera before that line and check if initialised. Maybe at onCreate.

Comment: this should go to comments!

Comment: this will be the solution

Comment: public void onResume()
    {super.onResume();
     mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
    } this is the line 510. this is not null.

Comment: @Drx for sure is something null at 510, try to make only 1 statement at 510

Comment: ohh, yah.. i checkd it i saw that the method called by onResume, the camera was null, but still dont know how would i fix that. i think i need to analyze each line :)

Answer (score 1):

At some point in your code you are setting `mCamera` to `null`.

It could be in your `onPause` or `onStop` methods, or even your `onStart` or `onResume` methods. Review the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try to realese the camera in onPause method

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#TaskReleaseCamera

Comment: yah, i have release the camera in my onPause, super.onPause();releaseCamera();